# cucumber runner files is not able to pickup features/classes when run from maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I am able to run my cucumber runner file(as JUnit) without any issues. Tests are picked up and running fine.

But when i run through maven, though maven points to the Runner file, unable to execute tests.

Please find my maven logs and pom.xml file. Can someone help me what is missing in pom.xml? or eclipse configuration?

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building LinenHousePOC 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ LinenHousePOC ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory E:\Programming\Cucumber\LinenHousePOC\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ LinenHousePOC ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ LinenHousePOC ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ LinenHousePOC ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ LinenHousePOC ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: E:\Programming\Cucumber\LinenHousePOC\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running runners.RunnerTest
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@7f7052
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.041 sec

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 13.463 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-07-03T10:45:17+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/19M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Following is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>LinenHousePOC</groupId>
    <artifactId>LinenHousePOC</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.47.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>2.41.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: can you please post your cucumber runner class as well?

Comment: You're missing build step in POM

Comment: what is your runner class file name? I don't see you have pointed maven POM to use any specific runner file to run in your configuration. use include tag to specify runner file name.

Answer (score 0):

Update in your POM build!!

use below configuration and run `mvn clean verify`. If you don't want to run tests in parallel, remove parallel, perCoreThreadCount and threadCountClasses tags. Make sure to update the regular expression to match your test naming convention **/Run*.java

```
         <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>acceptance-test</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>
                            <parallel>classes</parallel>
                            <perCoreThreadCount>true</perCoreThreadCount>
                            <threadCountClasses>10</threadCountClasses>
                            <argLine>-Xmx1024m</argLine>
                            <argLine>-XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/Run*.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Executing the tests from IDE is different from executing the tests from Command Line (Maven).

In IDE, the configuration, the context variables are automatically initialized or picked when we invoke the tests. Where as in the Maven Execution, few parameters needs to be explicitly mentioned.

when you invoke a test in :

**Executing tests with Maven (command line)**

`mvn clean test -Dcucumber.options="--format json-pretty --glue classpath:src/test/resources"`

The above command will set the glue from where the tests needs to be picked by maven to invoke the tests.

This glue information is same as the information passed as input in the `CucumberOptions` in the `CucumberRunner.java`

**Executing tests with Maven (using Maven Profile)**

Create a profile and pass the cucumber.options as input parameters as shown below:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>cucumber-tests</id>
    <properties>
      <cucumber.options>--glue src/test/resources</cucumber.options>
   </properties>

   . . . 
  </profile>
</profiles>
```